# How to replace text on the first selector with text from the second selector using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to replace text in this selector **.list-text > p**, with text from 
 this selector **.other-text > p**, and here the HTML:

```
<div class="list-text">
    <p>Text 1</p>
    <p>Text 2</p>
    <p>Text 3</p>
</div>

<div class="other-text">
    <p class="new-text">new text 1</p>
    <p class="new-text">new text 2</p>
    <p class="new-text">new text 3</p>
</div>
```

becomes

```
<div class="list-text">
    <p>new text 1</p>
    <p>new text 2</p>
    <p>new text 3</p>
</div>
```

i tried to write the js like bellow, but no luck:

```
(function($){
    $('.list-text p').each(function (i) {
        var $this_text = $(this).text();
        $('.other-text p').text($this_text);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Have I done the wrong thing?

Comment: show us your tried code first....

Comment: Post the jquery function that doesn't work and explain what's happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate over p tags and use current index to get text from required element:

```
$('.list-text p').each(function(i){
  $(this).text($('.other-text p').eq(i).text());
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a8o2ruLw/)**

Answer (score 2):

[text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) jq method accepts a function, you could use instead:

```
$('.list-text p').text(function (i) {
    return $('.other-text p').eq(i).text();
});
```

### -DEMO-